# Could not find a base address that matches scheme HTTPS error in IIS-hosted WCF

Tags: wcf, iis-7, https, mex, wshttpbinding

I almost have everything set up to use my WCF service over https. IIS application is up and running, I can read the svc and wsdl at localhost. So I went back to Visual Studio and tried to write a Client that can call the service. When adding the ServiceReference I get the following error:

*Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding MetadataExchangeHttpsBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].*

I've tried with the built-in development server and with IIS Express also. They both gave the same error.

Here's my web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="TransportSecurity">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SmartCook2.Server.ISmartCookServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="SmartCook2.Server.ISmartCookServiceBehavior" 
        name="SmartCook2.Server.SmartCookService">
        <endpoint address="https://localhost:6344/SmartCookService.svc" 
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity" 
          contract="SmartCook2.Server.ISmartCookService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" 
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which **address (URL)** did you use for trying to create your Service Reference in Visual Studio?? You should be able to either use the base address of the service, or the MEX address

Comment: When adding the service reference I used the Discover button in VS, and it found the service as `http://localhost:6344/SmartCookService.svc`. I also tried changing the address to https. It didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems VS didn't discover the address right, since it left out the application part. So the correct address for the service reference is :

`https://localhost/IISHostedSmartCook/SmartCookService.svc`